# Slide in text when icon is hovered

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've been trying to get an effect where:

1. Icon Font is shown, text beside it is hidden.
2. when hover on an icon, slide in the text that is hidden. Slide in from the right.

Here is what I've tried so far:

(Since it will take to much time, replaced icons with some random keyboard symbols)
http://jsfiddle.net/h9EX9/

```
ul li { display: inline-block; list-style-type: none; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; }
ul li span { display: inline-block; }
ul li a { display: inline-block; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;  }
ul li:hover a  { transition: all 1s ease-out; width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

[image]

This is the effect I'm trying to accomplish. Text and and width of comment slides from the right. But there are other icons besides this one. I hope its also possible to slide those when the width of the background expands.

So is this possible, if so how?

Comment: take a look at the code I've posted :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's your demo with some work done on the CSS. It's a little long winded but gets the job done without JavaScript using only CSS transitions for animation. For some reason it animated better using `max-width` instead of `width` but I'm not sure why.

#### **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/h9EX9/1/

When implementing properly, you might want to use an extra wrapper element to animate instead of the `<a>` as you will have multiple `<a>` elements in the "tags" button for example.

Comment: Thank you, just what I wanted. One problem. The tag will actually could have an unlimited amount. ether 3 or even 15. What would be the best way to show all of these tags without hidding them, like they do now when hovered?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the jQuery hover() function here's some demo code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".icon").hover(function(){ $(".text").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);}, function(){ $(".text").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);});
</script>
```

of course you must as you've mentioned set .text's display to none and don't forget to include the jQuery script in the head section of your HTML

**ps:** you can replace .icon and .text by any other CSS selector to select your icon or text example ul li a so $(".icon").hover will become $("ul li a").hover

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking after:
HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="comment-button">♥
        <div id="comment-button-text">Comment</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#comment-button').hover(
  function () {
      $(this).animate({
  width: '70px',
},1000)
      $('#comment-button-text').animate({
  width: '70px',
},1000)
  },
  function () {
         $(this).animate({
  width: '11px',
},1000)
          $('#comment-button-text').animate({
  width: '0px',
},1000)

  }
);
```

And some styling:

```
#comment-button{
background-color: #ababab;
width: 11px;
border-radius: 15px;
height: 15px;
padding: 10px;
color: red;
}
#comment-button-text{
   width: 0px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 16px;
left: 31px;
color: #8a8a8a;
}
```

Here is the Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xs4Nt/1/

Comment: Nice except is it possible to expand the width without pixels, eg: lets say there was more content then just "comments'. and can't predict the width.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this might help new people coming here...
This is a fix and improvement on [@SeekingKnowledge's][1] post (linked). Below is my version of the code, explained.

```
$("#closeText").hide(); $("#close").hover(function(){ $("#closeText").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);}, function(){ $("#closeText").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);});
```

Replace `#close` with your icon element's ID, and change all three `#closeText` with the element that contains your text's ID. You can customise the animation time by changing the value currently at 400 (measured in milliseconds), however, this is a good speed for my site. You also need to set `#close` CSS to have a z-index of 2 more than the z-index of the `#closeText`.
Remember to get jQuery!
[Here's](https://codepen.io/thelukaboss/pen/JjGPqqM) how I used it for one of my pages on my website (link to CodePen).
Hope this helped anyone looking here for answers!
Luka S